# Stored procedure with transaction, stops at transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I have 5 PC's that run the same Stored Proc on 1 SQL server. For the sake of giving an example, let's say it's a program that runs over night. A PC executes a stored proc with an userID, and based on it, will update multiple tables in SQL Server. And this is done for all 2000 users in the company. However, as we have 5 PC's doing this, we are working with table-locks and transaction.

99% of the time, the stored proc works as intended, but every now and then, the SP just seems to stop before the transaction. Here is a breakdown of my SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateClient @UserID @PCID
    (Declared variables etc)

BEGIN
BEGIN TRY

INSERT INTO dbo.log(event, PC_ID) values('The stored proc has been started by PC:', @PCID)
-- I have added these logging to my SP to try and find the issue but with no luck

BEGIN TRANSACTION T1

    INSERT INTO dbo.log(event, PC_ID) values('Transaction has been opened', @PCID)
    
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.MasterTable with (tablockx, holdlock)
    -- As we are having multiple PC's using the same SP at the same time, 
    -- we decided on using a table that is being read and locked when free by "the master" at that moment

    INSERT INTO dbo.log(event, PC_ID) values('Master has been claimed', @PCID)

    /**** Here we have a ton of UPDATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements taking place ****/

    INSERT INTO dbo.log(event, PC_ID) values('Tables have been updated', @PCID)
    INSERT INTO dbo.log(event, PC_ID) values('Master role will be released', @PCID) 

COMMIT TRANSACTION T1

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    INSERT INTO dbo.log(event, PC_ID) values(CONCAT('An Error has occurred:',ERROR_MESSAGE()), @PCID)      
END CATCH

INSERT INTO dbo.log(event, PC_ID) values('Stored procedure is now ending', @PCID)      
END
```

Having these run by external PC's, makes it harder to log so the dbo.log is all I have in this case. As said before, sometimes the transaction doesn't get executed and then I end up with a log like this (let's say I only had PC1 and PC2 running that night):

```
ID| Event                                   | PC_ID
1 | The stored proc has been started by PC: | PC1
2 | The stored proc has been started by PC: | PC2
3 | Transaction has been opened             | PC2
4 | Master has been claimed                 | PC2
5 | Tables have been updated                | PC2
6 | Master role will be released            | PC2
7 | Stored procedure is now ending          | PC2
8 | The stored proc has been started by PC: | PC1
9 | Transaction has been opened             | PC1
etc
```

This is where I am lost. PC1 starts the Stored proc, but doesn't get further then the first log line. PC2, which started at the exact same time, did however go through the whole thing. My first thought was that (somehow) the transactions colide. But what I find weird is that PC1's SP doesn't even execute stuff outside the transaction. My CATCH statement nor the extra log line in the end of the SP are executed.

In the end, PC1 just executes it's next SP with a new UserID (but that ultimately breaks stuff in the end)

Any ideas/suggestion on how to fix this problem? As said before, 99% of the time it works but that 1% is causing a lot of issues.

Comment: Your catch statement doesn't roll back the transaction therefore it may leave it open which would block forever. And you may also find that because you haven't rolled back the transaction your error won't get inserted into your log. Handling errors like this is very complex, there is [an excellent blog](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) I suggest you read.

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for the blog link. Seems very interesting. I've added a rollback as documented on there and I'm running everything again. Hopefully the error will be correctly logged this time. However, this makes me also think: Will the lack of rollback also cause my very last insert-line not to work as well? Because that one is outside the TRY-CATCH part?

Comment: Pretty sure it would cause that to fail - its depends on the error, but usually the transaction can't continue, hence why you rollback so you can then write to the database again. You need to do more than rollback, as per the blog you need to check for an open transaction, and maybe even the level of transaction, I forget now. Also you might want to look into the use of `set xact_abort on` to ensure all errors abort the transaction to give you consistent behaviour which is easier to handle.

Comment: It seems to me that your logging is most needed when an error occurs. If so, then you need some technique that will allow that information to survive a rollback. A table variable can be used for that (you dump the contents of the table variable into the final table after commit or rollback). And I believe that the db engine will automatically roll back any uncommitted transactions when the connection is closed (or reset) - which is consistent with your PC1 information.

Comment: Aside: Rather than using a table solely to hold a lock you might want to consider using [`sp_getapplock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get an _application lock_. It works with transactions and gives you more control, e.g. you can specify a `LockTimeout`.